# how to add labels to arrows avoiding conflicts with existing node shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

Ok, I've made the following diagram:

[image]

I want to add text labels to the various arrows (at the red points) and I want to ensure that the labels do not overlap the dotted lines, the arrow lines etc. So,

- What is a good way to add labels to the lines (hopefully compatible with the way I've coded the lines)?
- What is a good way to move the rectangles such that conflicts between the text of the labels and the lines of the rectangles and arrows are avoided?

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, arrows, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{redRectangle} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=red!20,
    node distance=0.65 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4 em,
    minimum width=3 cm,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{blueRectangle} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4 em,
    minimum width=3 cm,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{yellowRectangle} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=yellow!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4 em,
    minimum width=3 cm,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{greenRectangle} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=green!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4 em,
    minimum width=3 cm,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{blueDiamond} = [
    diamond,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text badly centered,
    inner sep=0pt,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{blueEllipse} = [
    ellipse,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{container} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.5 cm,
    dashed
]

\tikzstyle{empty} = [
]

\tikzstyle{line} = [
    draw,
    -latex',
    thick
]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    \node [empty](origin){};
    \node [redRectangle, right=of origin] (primaryxAODData) {primary xAOD data};
    \node [redRectangle, left=of origin] (primaryxAODMC) {primary xAOD MC};
    \node [blueRectangle, below=of origin](DxAOD0And1Lepton){DxAOD\\0 and 1 lepton};
    \node [blueRectangle, left=of DxAOD0And1Lepton] (DxAODMC) {DxAOD\\MC (also called TOPQ1)};
    \node [blueRectangle, right=of DxAOD0And1Lepton](DxAOD2Leptons){DxAOD\\2 leptons};
    \node [yellowRectangle, below=of DxAOD0And1Lepton](AnalysisTopPackage){AnalysisTop package\\TTHbbLeptonic};
    \node [blueRectangle, below=of AnalysisTopPackage](Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple){Mini-xAOD or flat n-tuple};
    \node [greenRectangle, below=of Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple](plots){plots};

    \node [container, fit=(primaryxAODData)(origin)(primaryxAODMC)](container1){};
    \node [container, fit=(AnalysisTopPackage)](container2){};
    \node [container, fit=(plots)](container3){};

    \path [line] (primaryxAODMC) -- (DxAODMC);
    \path [line] (primaryxAODData) -- (DxAOD0And1Lepton);
    \path [line] (primaryxAODData) -- (DxAOD2Leptons);

    \path [line] (DxAODMC) -- (AnalysisTopPackage);
    \path [line] (DxAOD0And1Lepton) -- (AnalysisTopPackage);
    \path [line] (DxAOD2Leptons) -- (AnalysisTopPackage);

    \path [line] (AnalysisTopPackage) -- (Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple);
    \path [line] (Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple) -- (plots);

    \node at (container1.north)[above]{production system};
    \node at (container2.south east)[right]{user grid or local};
    \node at (container3.south east)[right]{user grid or local};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next code shows you some examples:

```
\path [line] (primaryxAODMC) -- (DxAODMC) node[fill=white, pos=0.7, right=2mm]{label A};
```

draws a line between `primaryxAODMC.center` and `DxAODMC.center` and adds a node with text `label A` to the right of position 0.7 (1 is total path lenght) of this path. The node has a `fill=white` background which could cover any previous path.

You can change `fitting` nodes if you adjust their `inner sep`, as in:

```
\node [container, fit=(plots), label={[anchor=west]south east:user grid or local}, inner sep=7mm](container3){};
```

Instead of new nodes for labels for dashed nodes, you can use `label` node option:

```
    \node [container, fit=(primaryxAODData)(origin)(primaryxAODMC), label=above:production system](container1){};
```

And instead of `redRectangle`, `blueRectangle`, ... you can define a `Rectangle` with a parameter which will later define its color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, arrows, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{Rectangle} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=#1!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4 em,
    minimum width=3 cm,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{blueDiamond} = [
    diamond,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    text badly centered,
    inner sep=0pt,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{blueEllipse} = [
    ellipse,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    node distance=1.5 cm,
    text width=7 em,
    thick
]

\tikzstyle{container} = [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2 cm,
    dashed
]

\tikzstyle{empty} = [
]

\tikzstyle{line} = [
    draw,
    -latex',
    thick
]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    \node [empty](origin){};
    \node [Rectangle=red, right=of origin] (primaryxAODData) {primary xAOD data};
    \node [Rectangle=red, left=of origin] (primaryxAODMC) {primary xAOD MC};
    \node [Rectangle=blue, below=of origin](DxAOD0And1Lepton){DxAOD\\0 and 1 lepton};
    \node [Rectangle=blue, left=of DxAOD0And1Lepton] (DxAODMC) {DxAOD\\MC (also called TOPQ1)};
    \node [Rectangle=blue, right=of DxAOD0And1Lepton](DxAOD2Leptons){DxAOD\\2 leptons};
    \node [Rectangle=yellow, below=of DxAOD0And1Lepton](AnalysisTopPackage){AnalysisTop package\\TTHbbLeptonic};
    \node [Rectangle=blue, below=of AnalysisTopPackage](Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple){Mini-xAOD or flat n-tuple};
    \node [Rectangle=green, below=of Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple](plots){plots};

    \node [container, fit=(primaryxAODData)(origin)(primaryxAODMC), label=above:production system](container1){};
    \node [container, fit=(AnalysisTopPackage), label={[anchor=west]south east:user grid or local}](container2){};
    \node [container, fit=(plots), label={[anchor=west]south east:user grid or local}, inner sep=7mm](container3){};

    \path [line] (primaryxAODMC) -- (DxAODMC) node[fill=white, pos=0.7, right=2mm]{label A};
    \path [line] (primaryxAODData) -- (DxAOD0And1Lepton) node[midway, left]{label B};
    \path [line] (primaryxAODData) -- (DxAOD2Leptons)node[anchor=center,fill=white, midway]{label C};

    \path [line] (DxAODMC) -- (AnalysisTopPackage);
    \path [line] (DxAOD0And1Lepton) -- (AnalysisTopPackage);
    \path [line] (DxAOD2Leptons) -- (AnalysisTopPackage);

    \path [line] (AnalysisTopPackage) -- (Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple);
    \path [line] (Mini-xAODorflatn-tuple) -- (plots);

%    \node at (container1.north)[above]{production system};
%    \node at (container2.south east)[right]{user grid or local};
%    \node at (container3.south east)[right]{user grid or local};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance on this and for your tips on making some of the objects more generalised. Your approach does indeed work.

Would you happen to know if there is a more automated approach to creating diagrams like this in TikZ (so that I wouldn't have to edit sizes and whatnot in order to avoid overlap of elements)?

Comment: @d3pd Glad to help you. I don't know any automatic tool. `matrix` nodes can help you when the diagram has a regular distribution, but distance between nodes and where to place labels is always up to your criteria.