# Position of Label inside a box

Tags: tikz-pgf

Wants to place Label One (See the attached image) inside the bigger box. Please advice.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
calc,
fit,
positioning,
shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
rrbox/.style={%rounded red box,
rectangle,
draw, rounded corners, thick, fill=red!20,
minimum height=8mm, minimum width=24mm,
text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner 
xsep},
align=center
},
sum/.style={% summation
circle,
draw=black, minimum size=8mm,
append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \draw[thick,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, -]
        (\LN.north) edge (\LN.south)
        (\LN.west)   to  (\LN.east);
        %        \draw[blue] (\LN.center)  circle (1.414*4 mm);
    }},% end of nappend after command
    node contents={}
},
disk/.style={% cylinder
    cylinder, shape border rotate=90,
    draw, fill=red!20,
    aspect=0.25,
    minimum height=12mm, minimum width=54mm,
    align=center
},
container/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw, rounded corners,
    inner sep=4mm, yshift=2mm,
    node contents={}
},
line/.style={
    draw, thick, dashed, -latex',
},
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=8mm and 4mm,
    ]
    \node (sum) [sum]; % sumation
    \node (a11) [rrbox, above left=4mm and 18mm of sum.west] {First \\Box};
    \node (a12) [rrbox, left =of a11] {Second \\ Box};
    \node (a21) [rrbox, below=of a11] {Third\\ Box};
    \node (a22) [rrbox, below=of a12] {Fourth \\ Box};
    \node (container1) [container, fit=(a11) (a22),
    label={[anchor=north]Label One}];
    \end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I compile your code on my machine, the label is inside the box, i.e. I do not reproduce your screen shot. Do you want the label *outside* the box? If so, just set the anchor to south in `\node (container1) [container, fit=(a11) (a22),
    label={[anchor=south]Label One}];`.

Comment: I obtain the same result as @marmot

Comment: I don't know what is happening? Shown image is the output I am getting when I compile the same code such that getting 'Label One' outside the box. This example is the part of my earlier question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443446/layered-design-using-boxes-and-dashed-arrows and when I compile the provided answer, I am getting all the labels out of the containers.

Comment: To get the label inside the box use `label={[anchor=north]90:Label One}`...

Comment: In https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443446/layered-design-using-boxes-and-dashed-arrows I don't see any labels. Or are you referring to one of the two answers? If so, which one? Are you using an up-to-date TeX distribution? You tend to add packages that are not needed like `\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}` in this case. What happens if you do not load them?

Comment: @YogeshSharma, i test my answer to your preivous question (from which you extract mwe in your question) and it not produce images which you shown. it seems that you make some changes to code not shown in question, for example, instead of `label={[anchor=north]Some more Text}` you probably write in your test `label=Some more Text` or `label=above:Some more Text` or `label=90:Some more Text`.